# Are fold expressions fully supported in VS2017?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, fold-expression

I found an [interesting article](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/exploding-tuples-fold-expressions/) and tried its code with MSVS 2017:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args, typename Func, std::size_t... Idx>
void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, Func&& f, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    f(std::get<Idx>(t))...;
}

template <typename... Args, typename Func>
void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, Func&& f) {
    for_each(t, f, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}

template <typename T>
void Write(std::wostream & out, const T & t)
{
    out << t;
}

template<typename ...Args>
void WriteV(std::wostream & out, Args&... args)
{
    for_each(std::tuple<Args&...>(args...), [&out](auto& a) { Write(out, a); });
}

struct A
{
    int n;
    std::wstring s;
    double d;
};

    void main()
    {
        std::wostringstream out;

        A a{ 1, std::wstring(L"2"), 3.0 };
        WriteV(a.n, a.s, a.d);
    }
```

, but the code did not compile with errors:

```
error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token '...', expected ';'
error C3520: 'Idx': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
```

does it mean that VS2017 does not fully support fold expressions?

Comment: What line is this error occurring on?

Comment: Doesn't work in GCC or Clang, either, even with the necessary includes. This is possibly a cautionary tale about copy/pasting code from random websites ;)

Comment: @Caramiriel at line 3: f(std::get<Idx>(t))...;

Comment: This code lacks includes. Also it is not clear which VS version and compilation options you are using

Comment: @VTT VS version is 15.9.4

Comment: "Keen readers might have noticed that I lied in the above section. `(std::get<Idx>(t))...;` does not generate that sequence of calls to f."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code needs just a couple of syntax fixes:

```
(f(std::get<Idx>(t)), ...);
```

and

```
WriteV(out, a.n, a.s, a.d);
```

Note that this code is unnecessary long for some reason. It can be replaced with just

```
 template<typename ... Args>
 void WriteV(std::wostream & out, Args const & ... args)
 {
     (out << ... << args);
 }
```

Comment: … and `void main()` …

Answer (score 4):

This way is wrong

```
f(std::get<Idx>(t))...;
```

You have to choose.

(1) do you want to call `f()` only one time with all arguments? In this case you have to put the ellipsis ("`...`") **inside** the call

```
f(std::get<Idx>(t)...);
```

(2) or do you want (I suppose is the case, in your example) call `f()` with every argument (`N` argument, `N` calls)? In this case you can (starting from C++17) use template folding with comma operator adding a couple of parentheses

```
    (f(std::get<Idx>(t) , ...);
// .^...................^....^   <- comma and parentheses
```

The second way, pre C++17, can be simulated inside the inizialization of an (usually unused) array. Something as follows

```
using unused = int[];

(void) unused { 0, ((void)f(std::get<Idx>(t)), 0)... };
```